# Is there any python specific solution for conversion of an excel file to its respective pdf?

Tags: django, pdf, webserver, xlsx, aspose

I have been trying to convert an excel file to its pdf form.
But the django server is getting hanged.

I read about this issue with flask server also
https://forum.aspose.com/t/python-flask-web-server-hang-at-aspose-cells/232218/6

As of now have used aspose-cells python library which has dependency upon Java.
It works fine inside console but not with Django web server (as the server is getting hanged indefinitely)

```
import asposecells
import jpype
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import Workbook

workbook = Workbook("input.xlsx")
workbook.save("output.pdf")
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

I am trying it out on mac M2.

Comment: We did conduct a test and created a demo using Flask Web server, it worked fine. Don't forget import asposecells at the start of your program/code. Also, you may follow up the Aspose forum thread.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Its working fine on intel based processors. The issue is only with Mac silicon based chipsets. Please conduct a test once on a ARM based architecture and confirm as i am getting stuck on it.